# jquery index of element of a certain class

Tags: jquery

I have several elements of a certain class within a container and I want to get the index of that particular element. Suppose I have this HTML:

```
<div id="TheContainer">

  <div class="MyClass">My Class</div>
  <div class="SomeClass">Not My Class</div>
  <div class="SomeOtherClass">Not My Class</div>
  <div class="SomeClass">Not My Class</div>
  <div class="MyClass">My Class</div>
  <div class="SomeOtherClass">Not My Class</div>
  <div class="SomeClass">Not My Class</div>
  <div class="MyClass">My Class</div>

</div>
```

I want to get the index of MyClass. This is what I tried:

```
$('#TheContainer').on({
    click: function () { 

       console.log($(this).parent().children('.MyClass').index()); }

}, '.MyClass');
```

So for instance, if the user clicks on the third MyClass element, it should console 2. **The jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mg7tv/).**

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) has an optional element argument:

> `.index( element )`
>
> **element**
>
> Type: Element or jQuery The DOM element or first element within the
>   jQuery object to look for.

So in this case, you could just use `this` as that argument:

```
$(this).parent().children('.MyClass').index(this);
```

[**JSFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mg7tv/2/)

Comment: your example has an extra parenthesis, if you don't mind fixing.

Answer (score 4):

You're clicking the `.MyClass` elements, so just check the index of `this` in relation to a selecor passed to `index()`, in this case `.MyClass` :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#TheContainer').on('click', '.MyClass', function () {
        alert( $(this).index('.MyClass') );
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mg7tv/4/)

from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

> .index( selector )
>
> A selector representing a jQuery collection in which to look for an
>   element.