# Problems with multidimensional array and loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

This script crashes randomly with the message "unable to get property .length of undefined or null reference" referring to "matched_array_pics.length". It crashes for sure if I clone, append the same image twice to the #train div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var starting_pics = ["AN.gif", "CN.gif", "EN.gif", "GN.gif"];

    var an_array_pics = ["CN.gif", "EN.gif", "GN.gif", "AN.gif"];
    var cn_array_pics = ["EN.gif", "GN.gif", "AN.gif", "CN.gif"];
    var en_array_pics = ["GN.gif", "AN.gif", "CN.gif", "EN.gif"];
    var gn_array_pics = ["AN.gif", "CN.gif", "EN.gif", "GN.gif"];

    var grand_array_pics = [an_array_pics, cn_array_pics, en_array_pics, gn_array_pics];

    var i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < starting_pics.length; i++) {
        $("<img/>").attr("src", "images/" + starting_pics[i]).load(function () {
            $(this).appendTo("#main");
            $(this).addClass("pics");
        });
    }


    $("#main").on("click", ".pics", function () {

        var j = $(".pics").index(this); // gets the index for the matched_array_pics...
          console.log(j);

        $("#sidebar .pics").remove();
        $(this).clone().appendTo("#train");
        $(this).clone().appendTo("#sidebar");
        $("#main .pics").remove();

        var matched_array_pics = grand_array_pics[j];   // ... in grand_array_pics.

        var k = 0;

        for (k = 0; k < matched_array_pics.length; k++) {
            $("<img/>").attr("src", "images/" + matched_array_pics[k]).load(function () {
                $(this).appendTo("#main");
                $(this).addClass("pics");
            });
        }
    });
});       //end ready
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on?  Please make your best effort to allow testing of your code, for example, by providing a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line: `var j = $(".pics").index(this);` and I think it should be rewritten like this: `var j = $(this).index();` It'd be helpful if you could add `console.log(j);` just after the line in question to see what `j` ends up being. When this line executes `var matched_array_pics = grand_array_pics[j];` I think you're getting `undefined` because `j` is not a number when your code runs.

Comment: But I believe his syntax is correct also. The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/) say you can use index() to search through the set of matched elements

Comment: Passing (this) as an argument to .index() isn't the same as getting the index of (this). Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634846/jquery-index-of-element-of-a-certain-class

Comment: I know, using `$(this).index()` will get the index in relation to the siblings but using `$('.pics').index(this)`should get the index in relation to the set of matched objects, so can you explain how in this case the two return a different value, seems like `$('.pics')` would refer to all the children of `#main`

Comment: j returns a number 0 and 3. Changing the code to what you suggested works.

Comment: Well it is no longer crashing, but the logic in the code is not correct. Clicking picture AN should load an_array_pics into #main div, clicking picture GN should load gn_array_pics etc.

Comment: Can you put all this in a jsFiddle? You can use http://placekitten.com/ for your pictures.

Comment: Also, when you say "clicking AN should load an_array_pics, etc" you're describing a correspondence between some key and some value. I think you should refactor this code using an object instead of arrays. Take a look at this question and see how the solution is much cleaner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076429/why-is-this-simple-function-not-working

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. How do I place this in a jsFiddle? The pictures really do not matter. You can use any 4 pictures. They actually represent musical chords and the arrays that get loaded represent possible resolutions for these chords. Each image will also be linked to an mp3. As the final version will have 180 of these image/mp3 combinations, I have to get the prototype right.