# jQuery this element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I click on element `$(".tabs__controls__item")` Me need use "rotate" for child element `$('.status_acc')`

On page a lot of `$(".tabs__controls__item")` how i can use rotate only for clicked element this class `$(".tabs__controls__item")`?

I try this, but it's dont work

```
function fullDescriptionMob(){
    $(".tabs__controls__item").on('click', function () {
         $test = $(this).data('index');
        $test2 = "#tab" + $test;
        $test3 = $(this);

            if ($($test2).hasClass("active") === true){
            $($test2).removeClass("active");
                $test3.children($('.status_acc').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)'));


        } else {
            $($test2).addClass("active");
                $test3.children($('.status_acc').css('transform', 'rotate(45deg)'));
        }
    })
}
```

Class `status_acc` - children
Class `tabs__controls__item` - parent

Answer (score 0):

I decided. it's worked

```
function fullDescriptionMob(){
    $(".tabs__controls__item").on('click', function () {
         $test = $(this).data('index');
        $test2 = "#tab" + $test;
        // $test3 = $('$(this) > .status_acc');
        $test4 = $(this).children().css('color', 'red');


            if ($($test2).hasClass("active") === true){
            $($test2).removeClass("active");
                $test4 = $(this).children().css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');


        } else {
            $($test2).addClass("active");
                $test4 = $(this).children().css('transform', 'rotate(45deg)');

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture only the current class you must use:

```
$(this).parent().children('.tabs__controls__item').index(this);
```

see: [jquery index of element of a certain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634846/jquery-index-of-element-of-a-certain-class)